# The type initializer for 'LibSassNetProxy.SassCompilerProxy' threw an exception

Tags: virtocommerce

Has anybody come across this with version 2.8?

VirtoCommerce.Storefront.MvcApplication.Application_Error, 46, ERROR, 
Compiler error: The type initializer for 'LibSassNetProxy.SassCompilerProxy' threw an exception.

This is a deployment to a new 2012R2 server. We've got the same source code working on other servers already.

The platform is working fine. On the store front end, the problem manifests as:

http://[domain]/store/NAS/themes/assets/default.scss.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
http://[domain]/store/NAS/themes/assets/ajaxify.scss.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you haven't installed [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784).